# Is dialetheism falsifiable?

Tags: logic

I was reading an article on dialetheism and the liar paradox and i came across an interesting comment. The writer said that dialetheists may accept the law of non-contradiction just for the sake of defining a contradiction (a proposition made of contradictories, and contradictories by definition cannot bear the same truth value, which stabilishes the lnc), but then they will deny it too, leading to the contradiction "¬(a ∧ ¬a) ∧ (a ∧ ¬a)", which does no harm to the dialetheist since their world view accomodates this. So, is it even possible to falsify dialetheism at this point? It seems that even the very denial of dialetheism may be disregarded. That's why i generally dislike dialetheism, because their notion of negation and of meaning seems to lack the adequate strenght to properly convey a meaningful sentence. (Such as accepting the law of non-contradiction, but nonetheless failing to satisfy its meaning)
Is there any method to falsify dialetheism which doesnt end at the "one more contradiction does no harm" problem?

Comment: Keep in mind the principle of non-contradiction a la Aristotle is not falsifiable. His version was the most grounded “in the world”, in the Socratic method of debate, and it only got more far removed from the world since. Even in his master arguments, there was not enough to falsify it, just to concede meaningful debate would be impossible. This is his strongest argument for it, the elenchic argument. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-noncontradiction/

Comment: The lnc nor any other indemonstrable can be falsified. (Evidently) but that is in the sense that no higher principle can judge its truth value, but the law of non-contradiction, aside from dialetheism, still preserved the concrete notion of negation which entails the exclusion of the denied term, whilst dialetheism fails to satisfact this notion. Tho, from the article you sent, it seems that his elenchic argument only works against trivialism, not minimal dialetheism. (I.e there exists atleast one dialetheia, and that's all.)

Comment: It is not possible to falsify any sufficiently elaborate philosophical doctrine, not relativism, not solipsism, not nihilism, not even determinism. Falsification is generally irrelevant in philosophy beyond introductory levels. So if that is your reason for disliking dialetheism you need a new one. On the other hand, it is perfectly possible for a doctrine to be pointless, implausible or infertile regardless of what it has to say about falsehoods and contradictions. This said, dialetheism does admit some pure truths and pure falsehoods, if those are unsatisfactory it will go by the wayside.

Comment: Bear in mind that dialetheists typically consider that only a few contradictions are true. They reserve that status for semantic paradoxes or other situations where there is plausible reason to accept a sentence as both true and false. Dialetheists understand what it is for most contradictions to be false.

Comment: I regularly find myself is situation where I listened to someone say something, and someone else reply something which appeared to be a literal negation of what the first person was saying, and then I'd have to say "I think you're both right" and explain why, because human language is such that it's actually not that hard to come up with two sentences that appear to be exact negations of each other but actually are playing on different viewpoints or different interpretations of words and can both be true without a contradiction.

Comment: Wikipedia says "Critics argue that this merely reflects an ambiguity in our language rather than a dialetheic quality in our thoughts", but situations like this arise so often and people get so hang up on them (immediately believing that the other person must be wrong since there is an apparent contradiction) that it's hard to distinguish this from some "stronger" dialetheism.

Comment: @Conifold I agree that 'pointless' is a much stronger and more useful criterion for dismissing something than 'untrue'. 99% of everything is false anyway, but of the bit left that is true, 99% of that is a waste of time to think about. We'd best focus on things that actually have effects.

Answer (score 1):

Dialetheism on the logical level is characterized by the use of paraconsistent logics as metalanguages for characterizing the object language. In other words, indeed that is the case - the dialetheist will use a logic in which there are true contradictions expressible (without explosion) to describe the contradiction. Nothing paradoxical or strange about it, other than perhaps the purpose of the whole enterprise (I fail to grasp, honestly, how are these logics philosophically interesting in *this* way).

Comment: For why they are interesting, Graham Priest has written short stories that motivate these logics, because classical logic fails.

Comment: @JKusin I don't see anyone but Priest care so I don't think they fail so badly. I remember him arguing in some strange ways for dialetheism but I don't know if I've read the stories you refer to. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is falsifiable.

One way to falsify dialetheism is to show that the liar paradox can be resolved without accepting the existence of true contradictions. This could be done by showing that there is a way to interpret the liar paradox such that it does not lead to a contradiction.

Another way is to show that there are some consequences of dialetheism that are unacceptable. For example, one consequence of dialetheism is that anything can be proven. This is because if a proposition and its negation are both true, then any proposition can be derived from them.

Also if a dialetheic claim leads to demonstrably false or harmful consequences in the real world, it could be argued to be falsified. For example, if a claim like "Socrates is both wise and unwise" led to contradictory behavior or disastrous decisions, it might lose credibility I think

Comment: falsifiable usually refers to empirical falsification

Comment: I'm not sure why a true proposition would be falsified by consequences of adopting it. If the nazis endorsed a set beliefs logically the closest to their own but including the proposition "tanks don't exist", then WW2 would have ended in 2 days. The consequences would have been bad for them. But tanks do exist.

Comment: @abcga yes, and fortunately for us, Hitler did think, "this unique, new jet engine fighter is actually a bomber" or else the war would have ended the other way.

Comment: This answer is wrong in multiple ways. It also wrongfully claims that with dialetheism anything can be proven. Dialetheism does have more truths than classical logic, but is not trivial, not everything is true. It's resilience to the principle of explosion is exactly what makes it a useful logic in cases when contradictions are present.

Answer (score 0):

Santos[[17](https://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/48387/1/Santos%20R%20-%202017%20-%20Fitch%27s%20Paradox%20of%20Knowability%20and%20the%20Knower%20Paradox.pdf)] takes dialetheism to task for having an unacceptable theory of rejection. The negation/rejection distinction is supposed to be important to the formulation of a dialetheist standpoint, see e.g. [this section of the SEP article on dialetheism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/#AcceAsseDial).

But so perhaps the lesson to be learned is that just as there are points in arguments where the possibility of agreement breaks down, so are there points where *dis*agreement breaks down, too. Whether this confirms Aristotle's thesis (that the LNC is inescapable) "remains to be seen," though offhand it does seem to an extent that dialetheism undermines itself by being able to assert the LNC while appearing to reject it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is dialetheism falsifiable?

To falsify a theory, we need to exhibit one of its assertion which is contrary to facts.

But as always, it depends on how dialetheism is defined. Here is what Wikipedia says:

> Dialetheism ... is the view that there are statements that are both true and false. More precisely, ... that there can be a true statement whose negation is also true. ... Dialetheism is not a system of formal logic; ... it is a thesis about truth ...

Assuming that it is true that dialetheism says that there are true statements whose negation is also true, then this is sufficient to conclude that dialetheism is just false, at least if we assume the common-sense notion of truth.

There is no need for any argument, formal proof etc. We just need to refer ourselves to the common-sense notion of truth. You have to make up your own mind as to what this common-sense notion is.

> So, is it even possible to falsify dialetheism at this point? It seems that even the very denial of dialetheism may be disregarded.

You prove a theory illogical if you can exhibit two of its assertions that are mutually contradictory, but you falsify a theory by exhibiting at least one of its assertions that contradicts facts.

In the case of dialetheism, the assertion that there are true statements whose negation is also true is sufficient to falsify dialetheism.

You don't ask a false theory to tell you how to prove that it is false.

Answer (score 0):

**No. It doesn't really make sense to "falsify a system of logic".**

There are two manners in which a theory can be read: on the correspondent reading, a theory is about corresponding to a state of affairs, and therefore certainly may be falsified. For instance, phlogiston in the modern times is read as non-existent and false as a theory. But in a more pluralist spirit, a theory can simply be probed for pragmatic features or coherence without ontological commitment. The plurality of theories of various classical and non-classical logics is a great example. Classical or non-classical? Whatever works. In this case, one might not speak of falsifying dialetheism at all. What would make a logical theory false, after all? To insist so would seem to relive the centuries long preoccupation that somehow Euclidean geometry is right and no other geometries can exist. In retrospect, we accept that Euclidean geometry is not true or false, but adequate predicated upon a certain interpretation of the parallel postulate applied to a certain context. Axioms of logical systems are much the same animals.